# How can I do a 301 redirect?

Tags: regex, .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

i have this code in my htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^/?watch-([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)-tvshow-season-([0-9]+)-episode-([0-9]+)-online-free.html$ index.php?menu=episode&perma=$1&season=$2&episode=$3&lang=en [L]
```

the old one was

```
RewriteRule ^/?show/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)/season/([0-9]+)/episode/([0-9]+)$ index.php?menu=episode&perma=$1&season=$2&episode=$3&lang=en [L]
```

so i want the old to redirect to the new 
like this

```
Redirect 301  /?show/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)/season/([0-9]+)/episode/([0-9]+)  /?watch-([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)-tvshow-season-([0-9]+)-episode-([0-9]+)-online-free.html
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Redirect` directive doesn't use regex. Use `RedirectMatch` instead and you have to use back-reference in target URL:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/show/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/season/([0-9]+)/episode/([0-9]+) /watch-$1-tvshow-season-$2-episode-$3-online-free.html
```